# Ajax + Django : Ajax is not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-forms

I don't understand why my AJAX request is not executed by JQUERY when the method is well executed.

**I have a form, linked to a JQuery function event with AJAX method that send data to Django function.**

When I click on the save button, my page reloads while browsing the function to capture the event. It displays the alert well but does not send any information with AJAX. 
Is my function correct? Is this a problem with Django?

**This is my html form :**

```
<form method="post" id="insert_idea__form">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="insert_idea__titre">Titre de votre idée</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insert_idea__title" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="insert_idea__content">Contenu de l'idée</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="insert_idea__content" name="centent"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                                                        
                        </div> 
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Sauvegarder</button>  
                    </form>
```

**This is my JQUERY function :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
$("#insert_idea__form").on('submit',(function(e)

    alert("Stop");

    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "insert_idea" %}',
        type : 'POST',
        data: {
            'title': $("#insert_idea__title").val(), 
            'content': $("#insert_idea__content").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });

}));
</script>
```

**This is my url.py on Django :**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ajax/insert_idea/$', ideas.insert_idea, name="insert_idea"),
]
```

**This is my view :**

```
def insert_idea(request):
    title = request.GET.get('title')
    centent = request.GET.get('centent')

    return JsonResponse()
```

**If you can help me understand why no data is sent to the view? Why is the page reloaded?**

Thanks,
Eliott

Comment: first line inside your onSubmit handler needs to be `e.preventDefault()` to avoid page reload. Otherwise page reloads before ajax call can be made. Also you might want to return something in the JsonResponse of your view but that's not causing the problem. Let me know if it works, I will add it as answer then

Comment: as mentioned by Vaibhav, use ```e.preventDefault()``` in your jquery function. Also, in your view ```def insert_idea()``` use ```request.POST.get('title', '')``` and ```request.POST.get('centent', '')``` instead of ```request.GET.get('title', '')```
as you're sending a post request

Comment: By having `type="submit"` in the button you're submitting the form when you click it to the page it's on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is that the token *csfr* is missing in the sent data**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
        $("#insert_idea__form").on('submit',(function(e)
           e.preventDefault();    
            alert("Stop");

            $.ajax({
                url: '/insert_idea/',
                type : 'POST',
                data: {
                    'title': $("#insert_idea__title").val(), 
                    'content': $("#insert_idea__content").val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                }
            });

        }));
</script>
```